# How to prompt until condition is met?

Tags: javascript, loops, prompt

Im trying to prompt the user until the input is equal to one of the elements in the array?

```
do {
      var bestCities = ["miami","sanfrancisco","austin","chicago","phoenix"]
      var userInput = prompt('Whats your city?');
    } while (
        userInput !== bestCities[i]
      );
    alert('I love ' + i + ' also' );
```

Comment: You will need to loop through the array to check each item in it. Where is `i` defined in the code?

Comment: Your question is not really a question. You're trying. Ok. So what?

Answer (score 1):

Could be:

```js
var bestCities = ["miami","sanfrancisco","austin","chicago","phoenix"];
var userInput;

do{
  userInput = prompt('Whats your city?') 
} while (bestCities.indexOf(userInput) === -1);

alert('I love ' + userInput + ' also' )
```

> **[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf)** returns the position from an array.

`indexOf` returns `-1` when no matches were found. So the loop ends when it finds an index other than `-1`. For example `miami` is in the `0` position and `chicago` in the `3` position.

Comment: A correction in `while condition`, should be `bestCities.indexOf(userInput) === -1`, the loop will continue to run when the index is `-1` i.e.  still not find any elements. You can test pressing the  `Run code snippet` button

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better architecture:

```
var validCity = false;

while(!validCity) {
    var input = prompt("What is your city");
    if(bestCities.indexOf(input) != -1) validCity = true;
}
```

Comment: You could simply `break` without having additional variable

Comment: aside from semantics, the basic idea I think is communicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
      var bestCities = ["miami","sanfrancisco","austin","chicago","phoenix"]
      var userInput = prompt('Whats your city?');
    } 
while (bestCities.indexOf(userInput)==-1);
alert('I love ' + userInput  + ' also' );
```

**Just a check in array index will do the trick**

Answer (score 0):

An even better way to do it:

```
const bestCities = ["miami", "sanfrancisco", "austin", "chicago", "phoenix"];
let userInput;
do {
  userInput = prompt("Whats your city?");
} while (!bestCities.includes(userInput));
alert(`I love ${userInput} also`);
```

Note: This is just an improvement to the current most top answer.